# How to solve a runTime permission bug?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

In my application i want use **runtime permission** for gettin the **DeviceID**, **and for this I wrote code below:**

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) Constants.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Constants.currentActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return TODO;
}
uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

but I get an error on **return TODO;** and I'm not allowed to run my application.

Error in my LogCat:

```
Error:(175, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable TODO
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well ... Obviously the variable `TODO` is not defined anywhere. So, defined it, or return whatever you want ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, can you send to me code? thanks

Comment: What code? This is _your_ code ("and for this i write below codes"). If you are not knowing what you are doing, you maybe should go several steps back and start learning Java or Android, resp.

Answer (score 1):

"Solving" your error involves an one-liner change, viz.,
changing

```
return TODO;
```

to

```
return -1;
```

or `return False;` or `return Null;`, based on the function.

However, if you don't understand why this change had to be done, now should be a good(and I recommend that you do this) time to take a considerably big step back and try to grasp the fundamentals of programming itself(not Java or Android specific)

Answer (score 0):

This is auto generated code by android which tells that `getDeviceId` needs some permissions to be granted. So this code checks whether app has permission or not.

What is TODO  = It is some code that you have to complete. You can see all todos in your project by shortcut key double shift and type todo and hit enter on todo.

Here `TODO: Consider calling` means this app does not have this above permission and you have to ask permission.

Here `return TODO;` means you have to return some value like null or int based on your method requirement.

If you are new to android then use [this permission library](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) to ask permission from user.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) Constants.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Constants.currentActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return TODO;
}
uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

I hope this explanation will be useful for you. and feel free to ask any query if not clear in comment.